# Why are two custom objects defined in exactly the same way not equal?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Please have a look at this code:

```
Card  *first = [[Card alloc] initWithFace:@"Ace" andSuit:@"Hearts"];
Card *second = [[Card alloc] initWithFace:@"Ace" andSuit:@"Hearts"];

if ([first isEqual:second])
    NSLog(@"Equal");
else
    NSLog(@"Not equal"); //WHY???
```

NSLog tells me these two objects are not equal. But why? And what should I do to make them equal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to implement your own `isEqual:` method within the Card class.

This would compare the face and suit of the passed in card object to self, and return an appropriate BOOL value. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) for more details on the base (NSObject) implementation and how you should amend it.

An untested, typed-in-the-browser implementation would be something like:

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)compareObject
{
    if (self == compareObject)
        return YES;

    if (![compareObject isKindOfClass:[self class])
        return NO;

    Card *compareCard = (Card*)compareObject;
    if ([compareCard.face isEqualToString:self.face] && [compareCard.suit isEqualToString:self.suit])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

You must also implement `hash` such that two equal objects return the same hash value.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this as an answer to another question but it answers yours quite well:

---

`==` in Objective-C checks for identity. That is whether two pointers point to the same object.

To test for equality use: `[objectA isEqual:objectB]`. By default it does the same as `==` but it can be overridden to have custom equality.

Comment: Read the bit that starts: "By default..."

Answer (score 0):

"isEqual" means "Are they the same object?", which they are not. You want to test for "Have they the same value?".